# Convert String to Date Object in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which has a date string in the header. It is returned as part of an array but I need that date in the array to be a `Date Object` and not just a string.

My table is as follows

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4LFuZ/2/)**

`//  [[20th Jan, 33], [21st Jan, 44], [22nd Jan, 5],[23rd Jan, 17]]`

I use the following JS to get this array

```
var arr = $.map($('#bookedTable th:not(:first)'), function(el,i) {
    return [[$(el).text(), $('#bookedTable td:eq('+i+')').text()]]
});

console.log(arr)
```

Question: How can I return the string dates as date objects in my array?

Comment: Where's the year ? Is 33 for 1933 ? 2033 ? 8331 ?

Comment: For complex date parsing, I'd suggest you to look at moment.js. But I think you ask a little too fast, did you search for "javascript date parsing" ?

Comment: by default it can be this year 2014

Comment: So basically you need to convert [20th Jan, 33] into a date object right?

Comment: AJ that is correct, 20th Jan 2013 into a date object. So basically all string dates within the table and returned within the array. the 33 stays as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ran something like this function on all your dates in array :)

```
function parseThisDate(date) {
  dateParts = date.split(" ");

  return new Date(dateParts[2], translateMonthToNum(dateParts[1]), dateParts[0])
}

function translateMonthToNum(monthName) {
  if (monthName == 'Jan,') return 0;
  //todo: add all months you need
}
```

Comment: `'Jan,'` should return 0 since month are zero based.

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert a string to date as

> var myDate = new Date("2013/1/16");

You can clearly get the "2013/1/16" from the array provided the months are in numbers.

[click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info on date object in JavaScript.